# Python MySQL DB executemany does not work on one value

Tags: python, mysql, executemany

I am trying to do a batch insert for a single value (row), I am trying to use the executemany function to do so, but it will not work it returns `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`. However, when I add an extra value it does work

So...
It will return an error here:

```
entries_list=[("/helloworld"),
                ("/dfadfadsfdas")]
cursor.executemany('''INSERT INTO fb_pages(fb_page)
        VALUES (%s)''', entries_list)
```

But not here:

```
entries_list=[("/helloworld", 'test'),
                ("/dfadfadsfdas", 'rers')]
cursor.executemany('''INSERT INTO fb_pages(fb_page, page_name)
        VALUES (%s, %s)''', entries_list)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing `("/helloworld")` is the same as writing `"/helloworld"`. To create a tuple you need `("/helloworld", )`.

What you're doing is actually running this:

```
cursor.executemany('''INSERT INTO fb_pages(fb_page)
    VALUES (%s)''', ["/helloworld","/dfadfadsfdas"])
```

And now the error you're receiving makes perfect sense - you're supplying two arguments with only one place holder. Defining `entries_list` as follows would solve the problem:

```
entries_list=[("/helloworld",),
            ("/dfadfadsfdas",)]
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to making tuple with an additional `,` at the end as pointed by Karem

```
entries_list=[
    ("/helloworld",),
    ("/dfadfadsfdas",)
]
```

You could also just pass in lists and that will sort it out for you just as good **when you are using parameterized query**.

```
    entries_list=[
      ["/helloworld"],
      ["/dfadfadsfdas"]
]
```